# angular - can't get data with $http

Tags: angularjs

I build my angularjs app with Grunt and yeoman.

My host in `example.com` and my api is `example.com/api`

Then I try to use `$http` like:

```
$http.get('/api/posts').success(function (data) {
    console.log(data)    //the data is my index.html code
})
```

Can anyone tell me why the data I get is my index.html code ? And How can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the index.html code back when you try to access the page ('/api/posts') that does not exist or cannot be accessed directly, try seeing

> example.com/api/posts/

on browser address bar and see what it returns.

Comment: Is this related to `$routeProvider` configure? I have set `otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })`

Comment: Yes probably this may be the possible cause.